# Unable to cast object of type '' on type ''

Tags: c#, casting

I'm working to the server-side of my game, it's almost finished but today I had a problem...
This game is based on 2 modalities, touchdown and deathmatch, at the end of the game the server have to know the results. It's an online game.
When I end the match or a player get out, the server crashes, it should not be, it had just to return to the room.
It gives me this error :

```
[ERROR]: Unable to cast object of type 'FagNet.Core.Data.GameScore' to type 'FagNet.Core.Data.TDGameScore'.
   in FagNet.Core.Data.Player.SetNewTDStats(Boolean win)
   in FagNet.Core.Data.Room.BroadcastBriefing(Boolean result)
   in FagNet.Core.Data.Room.<BeginResult>d__2b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace ---
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__1(Object state)
   in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   in System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   in System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Could anyone help me!?
I need help :(

This is the source of FagNet.Core.Data.GameScore :

```
public class GameScore
    {
        public DateTime JoinTime { get; set; }
        public uint TotalPoints { get; set; }

        public virtual uint CalculateEXP()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And this is the source of FagNet.Core.Data.TDGameScore :

```
public class TDGameScore : GameScore
{
    public uint TDScore { get; set; }
    public uint TDAssists { get; set; }

    public uint Kills { get; set; }
    public uint KillAssists { get; set; }
    public uint Offense { get; set; }
    public uint OffenseAssists { get; set; }
    public uint Defense { get; set; }
    public uint DefenseAssists { get; set; }
    public uint Recovery { get; set; }

    public override uint CalculateEXP()
    {
        var ts = DateTime.Now - JoinTime;
        if (ts.TotalSeconds < 0 || TotalPoints == 0)
            return 0;
        return (uint)ts.TotalSeconds / 4 + (TDScore * 15) + (100 * TotalPoints / (500 + 2 * TotalPoints) * 14);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `SetNewTDStats(Boolean win)`? It looks like you are trying to cast something in there incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Would be interesting to see the code of FagNet.Core.Data.Player.SetNewTDStats(Boolean win) (I can't comment yet so had to write an answer).

My guess is that you are trying to cast an instance of type GameScore to TDGameStore, which isn't valid unless you assigned an instance of TDGameStore to a variable of type GameScore and then tried to cast that.  (sorry that's a bad explanation!)

I would add a copy constructor to TDGameScore such as:

```
public TDGameStore(GameStore gs) {
  JoinTime = gs.JoinTime;
  TotalPoints = gs.TotalPoints;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: If possible add me on Skype, 
My skype : thedragsterx

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of FagNet.Core.Data.Player.SetNewTDStats(Boolean win) :

```
public void SetNewTDStats(bool win = false)
    {
        var score = (TDGameScore) GameScore;
        TDStats.TotalMatches++;
        if (win)
            TDStats.Won++;
        else
            TDStats.Lost++;

        TDStats.TotalKills += score.Kills;
        TDStats.TotalKillAssists += score.KillAssists;
        TDStats.TotalOffense += score.Offense;
        TDStats.TotalOffenseAssists += score.OffenseAssists;
        TDStats.TotalDefense += score.Defense;
        TDStats.TotalDefenseAssists += score.DefenseAssists;
        TDStats.TotalRecovery += score.Recovery;
        TDStats.TotalTouchdowns += score.TDScore;
        TDStats.TotalTouchdownAssists += score.TDAssists;
        GameDatabase.Instance.UpdateTDStats(AccountID, TDStats);
    }
```